# Close clocked-in org task and clock-in next leaf task

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

When I am moving through a `TODO` list, I often want to complete the current task and clock into the next leaf node. In other words, I am performing a depth-first traversal of the task list.

#### Before

```
* TODO foo
** TODO foo-bar
   CLOCK: [...]
* TODO baz
** TODO baz-qux
** TODO baz-norf
```

Once I complete `foo-bar`, I want to be in the following state.

#### After

```
* DONE foo
  CLOSED: [...]
** DONE foo-bar
   CLOSED: [...]
   CLOCK: [...]--[...]
* TODO baz
** TODO baz-qux
   CLOCK: [...]
** TODO baz-norf
```

`foo-bar` has been marked complete. Since all of `foo`'s dependencies have been marked complete, it too becomes marked complete. Since `baz-qux` is the next leaf task, it becomes the clocked-in task. Since `foo-bar` and `foo` are complete, I also want them to be collapsed. For clarity I've omitted that from the above code block.

#### After (including collapse)

```
* DONE foo...
* TODO baz
** TODO baz-qux
   CLOCK: [...]
** TODO baz-norf
```

How can I accomplish this pattern with a single command?